# Drupal 7: Displaying nodes by grouping them based on a field

Tags: drupal

Is there a way to group nodes based on a node reference field and display them in a list.
Say, I have a content type Album, and nodes Album ABC and Album DEF of type Album. These are referenced in nodes of content type Track. How can I display all the albums with the referenced Tracks in which they are referenced as a list?

For example:

- Album ABC

  - Track 1
  - Track 2
  - Track 3
- Album DEF

  - Track 4
  - Track 5
  - Track 6

  and so on.

I have been using Drupal only for a few weeks now, Can anyone explain the answer given below??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a view filtering on the node type = album
2. Set the view output style to "HTML List"
3. Include the node reference field as a link to node in your field list
4. Click "theme information" then look at the name of the file that applies to the node reference field. Create a .tpl.php file with a candidate name that's specific enough for your needs will be something like views-view--viewname--fieldname.tpl.php. Click the link for the template file in use in theme information for this field, and views will show you the code in that file. Copy & paste that code to your new file
5. In the new file, you'll want to write a little PHP to output your links as a list. If you enable the devel module, put  in the page, and inspect what's available. One of them will be an array of links. Output that with

Comment: +1 I never understood how views worked but this is a pretty good explanation

Comment: Can you please explain how to-"Include the node reference field as a link to node in your field list".Thanks.

Comment: In the fields section of the view, click the plus sign. In the area that appears, there will be a select box. Change the dropdown filter to "Content", then find your node reference field in the select box.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still did not get it.. So, for the example I gave above should the node reference field to be selected is Content: Description(Appears in: node:track_page)?? I used this and only the album name is displayed. Also, it would be really helpful if you could explain the 4th step. Thanks, Ramya

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a little more..I'm very new to drupal and cannot figure out a way to use your answer. Please!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) or [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds).